# How to configure a basename in React Router 3.x

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, react-router-redux

I have an app running at a nested url as opposed to the root. Lets say `example.com/app`.

I read [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v2.x/docs/BasenameSupport.md) that in react router 2.x you could configure basenames.

How can this be done in react router 3.x?

FYI I am also using the `react-router-redux` package.

Answer (score 7):

This functionality does not exist in React Router anymore. I went through a similar problem and found this fix.

**Step 1:** Install History (3.0.0)

`npm install --save history@3.0.0`

**Step 2:** Import { useBasename } from history in your router file (the file with `<Router>`):

`import { useBasename } from 'history'`

**Step 3:** Modify your `<Router>` like the below example:

`<Router history={ useBasename(() => browserHistory)({ basename: '/app' }) }>`

Comment: Bingo. Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the section on configuring histories in the React Router docs is what you're looking for:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#customize-your-history-further

Here's a full example integrating with react-router-redux (with some unnecessary info excluded):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

import Root from './containers/Root';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const historyConfig = { basename: '/some-basename' };
const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)(historyConfig);

const store = configureStore({ initialState, browserHistory });
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: (state) => state.router,
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root history={history} store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I think this only applies to react-router 2.x

Comment: React router 3.x is essentially 2.x without the deprecated Apis. I would give this a shot and post any errors

Comment: ```Uncaught Error: Expected the routing state to be available either as `state.routing` or as the custom expression you can specify as `selectLocationState` in the `syncHistoryWithStore()` options. Ensure you have added the `routerReducer` to your store's reducers via `combineReducers` or whatever method you use to isolate your reducers.```

Comment: Check the example above. The third parameter to syncHistoryWithStore is an options object. selectLocationState is passed a selector that points to your routing state. If you don't want to specify this, name your router stating "routing" in your root combineReducers as the error states.

Comment: Seems like the link is broken. Anyone know where this lives now?

Comment: Updated the link.