# react router did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, react-router-redux

I am trying to redirect the page to a different component and I'm getting `did not match any route` error.

React Router Version:

```
 "react-router": "2.4.0",
 "react-router-redux": "4.0.4",
```

Webpack.config file: Output:

```
 output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/SurveyMaintenance/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
```

App start:

```
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

   <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

my Route.js file:

```
<Route path="SurveyMaintenance/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={SurveyMaintenancePage}/>
        <Route path="surveydetail/:id" component={EditSurveyPage} />
    </Route>
```

Link element:

```
<Link to={`surveydetail/${survey.Id}`} onClick={editSurvey}></Link>
```

Error:[image]
Address:
 [image]

the address looks correct but still its throwing this error when clearly there is a component assigned to that address.
I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Solved this Problem by just adding a '/' before surveydetail. like this.

```
<Route path="SurveyMaintenance" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={SurveyMaintenancePage}/>
            <Route path="/surveydetail/:id" component={EditSurveyPage} />
        </Route>

<Link to={`surveydetail/${survey.Id}`} onClick={editSurvey}></Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use full path and you don't need the trailing slash, you also need to set `publicPath: '/'`

```
<Route path="SurveyMaintenance" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={SurveyMaintenancePage}/>
            <Route path="surveydetail/:id" component={EditSurveyPage} />
        </Route>
```

--

```
<Link to={`/SurveyMaintenance/surveydetail/${survey.Id}`} onClick={editSurvey}></Link>
```

if you want to use publicPath, you need to add a basename for your history like this
[How to configure a basename in React Router 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181889/how-to-configure-a-basename-in-react-router-3-x)

Comment: i just tried what you recommended and the address when:
http://localhost:3000/SurveyMaintenance/SurveyMaintenance/surveydetail/449

Comment: please see the update answer, you need to set basePath: '/'  or add basename to react-router